# Test statistic for the geometric distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, geometric-distribution

I start with a sampling distribution of an unknown discrete probability distribution with PMF $g(x)$. I want to test if this distribution is in fact a geometric distribution, this is my $H_0$. Furthermore I have good reason te believe that "checking for"
$$\hat{g}(1)(1-\hat{g}(1))-\hat{g}(2)=0$$
is a good criterion to do this in my case.

(Note that you obtain $p(1-p)-p(1-p)=0$ if $g(x)$ corresponds to a geometric distribution)

So I want to build a test statistic, using this criterion. And here starts my question:

1. I have never encountered a test statistic like this, and I want to learn about the art of creating test statistics. When I browse the internet looking for things like this, I encounter the classical test statistics which I do know, but I want to learn more about the techniques and ideas behind the creation of a test statistic.
2. In this case, starting from  $\hat{g}(1)(1-\hat{g}(1))-\hat{g}(2)$, how to proceed? How can I even derive the distribution of $\hat{g}(1)$ and $\hat{g}(2)$? In each case the test statistic itself will, under $H_0$, be centered around $0$. My estimators for $\hat{g}(1)$ and $\hat{g}(2)$ are estimated in the following way:

I have an i.i.d. sample size $n$ from a distribution where
$$\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=p  \text{ and } \mathbb{P}(X_i=2)=(1−p)p,$$ and I observe $X_i=1$ $A$ times and $X_i=2$ $B$ times, then  $\hat{g}(1)=\frac{A}{n}$ and $\hat{g}(2)=\frac{B}{n}$.

Intuitively I would say that my test statistic will be approximately normally distributed (for large n) with mean $0$.

Comment: What do you mean that "your estimators are MLE"? You should include in your answer how you derive these estimators.

Comment: Thanks, it should be more clear now.